# Scrolling in CSS, Page not fitting correctly, Scrolling effect

Tags: html, css

For my web page, while creating the background image it is not perfectly fitting. Like i want scrolling effect but only half of the image is fit to the screen there is no scroll coming. What i am expecting is whenever you enter the landing page of the site you will get background image with scrolling effect.[image: The below image is static]

The above image is static image.
what kind of image I want is pasted below

[image: Scrolling effect image]

for the second image there is scroll bar at right side.
I tried all the combinations like,
overflow-scroll, background-image: cover etc. How to make the background image moveable? vertically.

```
html{
    background: url("homepagev1.png");
    background-position: relative ;
    content: " ";
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(0.8);
    background-size: 90%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: flex;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 10vh; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Code snippet of Html

```
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" class="header-branch">pagename</a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li> 
            <a href="accounts/signup" class="webonlyversion">signup</a>                 
        </nav>
    </header>
    <footer>
    <ul class="main-link-mob">
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">JOIN COMMUNITY</a></li>
   </ul>
        <ul class="main-link-web">
            <b>"BE A PART OF THE COMMUNITY AND EXPLORE NEW THINGS"</b>
            <li><a href="">SOCIAL</a></li>
            <li><a href="/aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
       </ul>
       <div class="footer-sm">
           <a href="#">
                <img src="{% static 'icons/gmail.png' %}" alt="gmailicon">
           </a>
           <a href="#">
              <img src="{% static 'icons/twitter.png' %}" alt="twittericon">
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="{% static 'icons/instagram.png' %}" alt="instagramicon">
          </a>          
      </div>     
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: We'll need to see some of your code.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Can you please review now? I have edited the code and added styling.

Comment: Can you provide a `codepen` or `snippet` with both HTML and CSS?

Comment: @DavidYKHan Is this sufficient? Can you review now??

Comment: @AravindaKS Looks like a great question now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? You can not use `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain`, but you can still set it to `100%` of the width.

```css
body {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/5990692/pexels-photo-5990692.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

div {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 8em auto;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5em;
  opacity: 0.5;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div> Hello </div>
```